# Hosted file is downloaded damaged by IE

Tags: apache-2.2, internet-explorer, cdn

I have a ZIP file hosted via Apache with Akamai as CDN, the problem is when trying to download it with IE (and just IE) it is damaged and I'm unable to open it.

Since the problem occurs in other computers in different locations I've discarded network settings (firewall, proxy, etc).

I don't even know where start to look? What would be a possible cause for this to happen?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to solve the problem in the server (or CDN), I've verified it's not a client error

Comment: How did you confirm that the original file was not damaged?

Comment: I downloaded by SSH directly from the server and with Firefox it downloads fine

Comment: What size is the file?

Comment: It's about 30MB

Comment: Which version of IE? Have you tried doing a binary diff on what IE downloads vs. the original file?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd suggest is to try opening the "zip" file in notepad or your favorite plain text editor. You may find that IE has an HTML page instead of a zip file (you'll need to read the page to see *why*)

Comment: Why is this a -? This has happened to me quite a few times, especially with incorrect content-type headers

Comment: In fact, FireFox is actually a horrible offender of this, but the other way around. If the content-type is not set correct (or missing) it dumps a .html extension onto the end of the download, doesn't tell you about it, and then you're stumped as to why when you open your ZIP file you get a webpage full of gobbeldygook

Comment: Thanks, the content-type is fine. I tried what you told me though